# Plotting 4 panels with different log transformations on the axes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got data I want to plot with `ggplot2` using 4 panels, where each panel has a different combination of "linear"/"log" transformation on each axis:

- the top-left panel plots the data in "linear-linear" scale,
- the top-right panel plots the data in "log-linear" scale `+ scale_x_continuous(trans = 'log2')`,
- the bottom-left panel plots the data in "linear-log" scale `+ scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log2')`,
- the bottom-right panel plots the data in "log-log" scale `+ scale_x_continuous(trans = 'log2') + scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log2')`.

In short, I would like four plots on these different scales put together so that they share the same legend (the legend should appear once in the entire plot).

Here is a small sample of data.

```
data = data.frame(
    x = c(  seq(1,10),   seq(11,20)),
    y = c(2^seq(1,10), 2^seq(11,20)),
    type = c(rep("T1", 10), rep("T2", 10))
)
```

This is what I've achieved so far (see code below to make this plot below):
[image]

Unfortunately, that the x- and y- axes of the log-log transform do not show the real values of the data, but rather the `log` of the actual values (similar in the other scales). I want the axes in the log-log panel to look like an actual `+ scale_x_continuous(trans = 'log2') + scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log2')` like this:
[image]

## Code

I extended the original dataframe to plot it in four panels like this:

```
make.data.for.four.panels <- function(D) {
    linearlinear = "Linear-Linear transform"
    loglinear = "Log-Linear transform"
    linearlog = "Linear-Log transform"
    loglog = "Log-Log transform"
    
    num.values = length(D$x)
    DD = data.frame(
        x = c(D$x, log(D$x),     D$x , log(D$x)),
        y = c(D$y,     D$y , log(D$y), log(D$y)),
        type = rep(D$type, 4),
        scale = c(
            rep(linearlinear, num.values),
            rep(loglinear, num.values),
            rep(linearlog, num.values),
            rep(loglog, num.values)
        )
    )
    DD$scale = factor(
        DD$scale,
        levels = c(linearlinear, loglinear, linearlog, loglog)
    )
    return (DD)
}
augm.data = make.data.for.four.panels(data)
```

and plotting is simply:

```
g = ggplot(augm.data, aes(x = x, y = y, linetype = type, colour = type)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    labs(
        colour = "Type",
        linetype = "Type",
        x = "n",
        y = bquote(F[n])
    ) +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
    facet_wrap( ~ scale, scales = "free", nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
plot(g)
```

Comment: Probably easiest using patchwork to combine the plots and the legend.

Answer (score 1):

Besides `patchwork` or ... one option would be the `ggh4x` package which via `facetted_pos_scales` allows to individually set the scale in a facetted plot:

```r
library(ggh4x)
library(ggplot2)

scale <- expand.grid(
  scale_x = c("Linear", "Log"),
  scale_y = c("Linear", "Log")
)

data <- data |>
  merge(scale)

ggplot(data, aes(
  x = x, y = y,
  linetype = type, colour = type
)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  labs(
    colour = "Type",
    linetype = "Type",
    x = "n",
    y = bquote(F[n])
  ) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  facet_wrap(~ scale_x + scale_y,
    scales = "free", nrow = 2, ncol = 2,
    labeller = function(labels) {
      list(
        paste(
          paste(labels[[1]], labels[[2]], sep = "-"),
          "Transform"
        )
      )
    }
  ) +
  facetted_pos_scales(
    x = scale_x == "Log" ~ scale_x_continuous(trans = "log2"),
    y = scale_y == "Log" ~ scale_y_continuous(trans = "log2")
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Well, thank you very much for the effort... but it does turn out that  `patchwork` (which I didn't know) is quite easy to use. Not entirely trivial, but rather easy. Please, leave your answer here for future reference and as a good alternative to patchwork.

Answer (score 0):

I was pointed to `patchwork`. Here's the solution I came up with:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(dplyr)
require(patchwork)

data = data.frame(
    x = c(  seq(1,10),   seq(11,20)),
    y = c(2^seq(1,10), 2^seq(11,20)),
    type = c(rep("T1", 10), rep("T2", 10))
)

base_plot = 
    ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y, linetype = type, colour = type)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    labs(
        colour = "Type",
        linetype = "Type",
        x = "n",
        y = bquote(F[n])
    ) +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")

g11 = base_plot +
    labs(title = "Linear-Linear scale")
plot(g11)

g12 = base_plot +
    labs(title = "Log-Linear scale") +
    scale_x_continuous(trans = "log2")
plot(g12)

g21 = base_plot +
    labs(title = "Linear-Log scale") +
    scale_y_continuous(trans = "log2")
plot(g21)

g22 = base_plot +
    labs(title = "Log-Log scale") +
    scale_x_continuous(trans = "log2") +
    scale_y_continuous(trans = "log2")
plot(g22)

# notice that it is a '&' and not a '+' between 'plot_layout' and 'theme'!
g = (g11 | g12) / (g21 | g22) +
    plot_layout(guides = "collect") &
    theme(legend.position='bottom')
plot(g)
```